# Fail Jupyter Notebook installation on clean Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ipython, ubuntu-14.04, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

**How do I install develompment version of Jupyter Notebook?**

```
$ wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
$ sudo python get-pip.py
$ sudo pip install virtualenv
$ cd ~
$ virtualenv local/python/jupyter
$ source local/python/jupyter/bin/activate
$ git clone --recursive https://github.com/ipython/ipython.git
$ cd ipython
$ pip install -e ".[notebook]"

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jupyter-notebook (from ipython==4.0.0.dev0) (from versions: )
Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable (use --allow-external jupyter-notebook to allow).
No matching distribution found for jupyter-notebook (from ipython==4.0.0.dev0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be you have to install from the Jupyter repo now as things were moving around since the release of jupyter? Next releases will not be only for ipython but also for other kernels like julia and bash etc.

From https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_notebook

```
Create a virtual env (ie jupyter-dev)
ensure that you have node/npm installed (ie brew install node on OS X)
Clone this repo and cd into it
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install -e .
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a Julia or R Kernel?

Comment: @Jean-Pat you can look at this https://try.jupyter.org/ for several  languages. Jupyter can support multiple kind of kernels, so not only Ipython but also Bash or Julia or R. You can see the notebooks there.