# Fixing a failed upgrade to Jupyter complete uninstall/reinstall Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When I upgraded to Jupyter on Ubuntu 14.04 most everything works but the javascript loads for extensions..

I'm kind of giving up and need to wipe and start over but not entirely sure how to: (I know I should use virtualenv s but for the most part this has worked great 'till now.)

1) best uninstall, insure it is completely uninstalled and then re-install. It was installed/upgraded with pip (sudo)

2)I had previously installed IPython Dev via git, but see no trace of similar instructions for Jupyter? (this looks like it might be the answer to this part? [Fail Jupyter Notebook installation on clean Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29625479/fail-jupyter-notebook-installation-on-clean-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

don't want to dig myself a deeper hole...

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else manages to mess it up as badly as I did...

Well I got it mostly sorted out...  I removed anaconda from my bashrc file.. then I removed all instances of IPython and Jupyter form my base system files.. I used Pip uninstall for most stuff and anything left I removed via the file system, I checked carefully in the system dist-packages folder as well as numerous others using locate and find to make sure I killed it all. Then a sudo install Jupyter and a "python setup.py install" in the IPython extensions directory and I seem to be mostly back to normal....